# Hide custom middle button when navigation push swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, uitabbar

I have 3 bar items in my tabbar, the middle one I set disable and overlay it with my middle custom button like this

[Swift 3 - How do I create a prominent button on a tab bar (e.g. camera button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477440/swift-3-how-do-i-create-a-prominent-button-on-a-tab-bar-e-g-camera-button)

I want to hide bottom bar when navigation pushed a new screen. I try this but it does not work because viewDidDisappear was never called

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    centerButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Coud you guys show me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo there. Use super.viewDidDisappear()

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    centerButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set that property for the view controller that **is** pushed. It is important to notice that setting it in `viewDidLoad` is too late. You should set in when the view controller instance is initialized instead:

```
class PushedVC: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit() {
        hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }

}
```

Of course you could also just check the checkmark `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` for the specific view controller when using storyboards.

To make sure that your center button gets hidden / shown with the tab bar in this approach you have to add it as a subview of the tab bar in your `UITabBar` subclass. Then you override `hitTest` to make it fully tappable (of course that is only needed if the button exceeds the tab bar's frame):

```
class TabBar: UITabBar {

    let centerButton = ...

    // ...

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if centerButton.frame.contains(point) {
            return centerButton
        }

        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Button my custom button is not part of tabbar controller. And if I add it to tabbarcontroller view, I cannot click on the upper part of the button because it is out of the tabbar view. Note that my button is bigger than the tabbar (half of it is in the tabbar and the other half is not)

Comment: Where do you add the button instead? And what do you want to hide? Only the button? Or the whole tab bar including the button?

Comment: The whole bar include the button. When navigation controller push a new screen, my tabbar and also my custom bottom should be hidden. My button looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477440/swift-3-how-do-i-create-a-prominent-button-on-a-tab-bar-e-g-camera-button

Comment: So with my solution the bar gets hidden correctly but the button stays in place? Do I get that correctly?

Comment: True. And if I add the button to tabbar (tabbar.addSubview(button)). Then it works but my button is higher than the tabbar, and we can only click on part of the button (within the tabbar view). Any idea rather than using hit test?

Comment: In what class do you add the button right now? Not in the tab bar controller subclass but?

Comment: And btw... What's wrong with the `hitTest` approach?

Comment: hitTest seems too much. If I cannot find any answers than hitTest is definitely my choice. I add the button to the controller that hosts tabbar (CustomTabbarController.swift)

Comment: @coinhndp Updated my answer.