# Customise Tab Bar with rounded button Issue swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, swift4, swift5

I have been customising tab bar with rounded button in center and set corner radius curve as well, I have set in storyboard as below,

[image]

I have rendered image as original, but my issue is when I run in simulator, the upper half of rounded circle is missing as shown in image,

[image]

I have set class for UITabBar,

```
class ProminentTabBar: UITabBar {
    var prominentButtonCallback: (()->())?
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let items = items, items.count>0 else {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
        
        let middleItem = items[items.count/2]
        let middleExtra = middleItem.imageInsets.top
        let middleWidth = bounds.width/CGFloat(items.count)
        let middleRect = CGRect(x: (bounds.width-middleWidth)/2, y: middleExtra, width: middleWidth, height: abs(middleExtra))
        if middleRect.contains(point) {
            prominentButtonCallback?()
            return nil
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

and tabbarcontroller added below lines as well,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let prominentTabBar = self.tabBar as! ProminentTabBar
    prominentTabBar.prominentButtonCallback = prominentTabTaped
}

func prominentTabTaped() {
    selectedIndex = (tabBar.items?.count ?? 0)/2
}
```

This source was from stack overflow ticket:- [How do we create a bigger center UITabBar Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527738/how-do-we-create-a-bigger-center-uitabbar-item)

Does anyone have solution for this>?

Answer (score 0):

make

```
tabbar.clipsToBounds = false
```

You can change it via code or in StoryBoard

Keep coding........ :)